# Knockout adding rows into a foreach loop that creates columns

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js

I used to have a View that looked something like this:

```
<div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
    <h4 class="text-center">Row 1, Col 1</h4>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
    <h4 class="text-center">Row 1, Col 2</h4>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
    <h4 class="text-center">Row 1, Col 3</h4>
</div>
<div class="row">
//Repeat...
```

Basically 4 Rows, with 3 columsn in each, setup using Bootstrap. 
I've now moved the code for `columns` into a knockout template and add them using a foreach loop:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: myArray">
    <my-widget params="value: $data"></my-widget>
</div>
```

This works nicely, but one thing is missing, the `row`. How can I add a `div row` every 3 `columns`?

Answer (score 1):

Are you saying that `my-widget` component only contains the 3 columns, and that you want a `div row` to encompass these 3 columns?

It looks like this should be as easy as adding the `div row` to the top of the Knockout template, like this:

```
<div class='row'>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
        <h4 class="text-center">Row 1, Col 1</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
        <h4 class="text-center">Row 1, Col 2</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
        <h4 class="text-center">Row 1, Col 3</h4>
    </div>
</div>
```

If that isn't feasible you could also do this:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: myArray">
    <div class="row">
        <my-widget params="value: $data"></my-widget>
    </div>
</div>
```

If neither of these are correct then I suggest you show us the template, as well as the relevant viewModel code.

Answer (score 0):

Access $index from the binding context inside of your foreach
https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html

```
<div data-bind="foreach: myArray">
    <!-- ko if: $index() !== 0 && $index() % 3 === 0 -->
    <div class="row">
    <!-- /ko -->
    <my-widget params="value: $data"></my-widget>
</div>
```